# Disable OSX Mavericks' "Do you want to try to reopen its windows again?" popup

Tags: osx-mavericks, crash-reports

I'm using OSX's launchctrl functionality to automatically relaunch an app after it crashes.

Unfortunately, when the app relaunches, it launches together with an action window that reads:

"The last time you opened MyAppName, it unexpectedly quit while reopening windows. Do you want to try to reopen its windows again?"

I tried to suppress it by calling NSQuitAlwaysKeepWindows

```
defaults write -app /Path/to/app/MyAppName.app NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false
```

But this only works some of the time - I'd say that the popup window launches 50% of the time.

This window requires action and blocks the app from jumping into a full screen mode.

I'm on OSX 10.8.4

Thanks for any ideas ...

Jeremy

Answer (score 2):

Open the folder "~/Library/Saved Application State" and look for a file like "some.url.MyAppName.savedState".

Deleting this file might probably solve the problem, at least it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix mine by deleting the Envelope Index file(All the files with the name "Envelope Index") under /Library/Mail/V2/MailData folder.
Then restart the mac.